# JPA how to get some fields not all fields

Tags: java, jpa

I have Master table and Details table
  1- master -Employee(id int primary Key, name varchar2, address_Id int foreign key)
  2- details- Address(id int primary key,  block varchar2,  building varchar2,  area varchar2)

I use the JPA to get the Object and i want some fields not all, i want
 (Employee.id, Employee.name, Address.area) **only**  
 so how can i do this without get all fields??
  thanks.

Comment: If there is not any relation between these two tables then if you use `createQuery` or `namedQuery` I think you need to get two objects. Or also you can use `nativeQuery`

Comment: there is a relation, but when i get the object, i get all fields :(

Comment: Yes if you return object then you will get all fields. So best way is to use `nativeQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You do that by using a query:

```
select e.id, e.name, a.area from Employee e left join e.address a where ...
```

Such a query will return a `List<Object[]>`, where each object array contains the three selected elements.

But you will probably not gain anything by selecting only those fields, because what generally costs when executing database queries is to find the data to retrieve and execute the joins between the tables. You'd better keep using your entities, and use the following query instead, which will return Employee instances, with their address already loaded:

```
select e from Employee e left join fetch e.address where ...
```

This will return a `List<Employee>`.

Comment: thanks B Nizet:) , but the result is same, the result get all fields

Comment: Have you read my answer? It explicitely and clearly explains that you can retrieve only those 3 fields (and shows how to do), but that it's usually useless because there is no significant performance gain in doing so.

Comment: thanks on the clarification, but my question because i have table contains 3 fields contains 5000 varchar as text in more than 3 languages, so i want to load only one field for one language not 3 languages.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late, but still wanted to answer in case someone may also face this problem: have you considered to try fetch types like lazy and eager? With these you may get all the fields that are just marked as "eager" directly, "lazy" fields are fetched